# Line's number using regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible to get the line's number using regex in Notepad++;

what I want to do, is replacing:

```
line1
line2
line3
etc..
```

with

```
1-line1
2-line2
3-line3
etc..
```

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to do that with regular expressions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Notepad++ can do that by using the TextFX plugin. Select the lines and then select `TextFX->TextFX Tools->Insert Line Numbers` from the menu bar.

This will add line-numbers padded to 8 places with leading zeros. To get them in the form described in your question, you can use a regex-replace with these values:

search for: `^0+([0-9]+)\s`

replace with: `line\1-`

Comment: line does not work for me. It does not result in the line number but in the text "line" instead.

Answer (score 29):

Older question, but I had this question myself today and found another answer than those presented already.

Column Editor (Alt + C) provides a way to insert numbering.  Options exist to choose the starting number, interval, and how often each number should be repeated.  Place the cursor on the first position of the first line and increment by one to mimic the actual line numbers.

Comment: This is slick.  Kinda related to this, is column editing mode, which you can do by holding down ALT while you select rows of text (e.g. with the keyboard, hold ALT+SHIFT+DOWN ARROW, or mouse ALT + Click and drag down).  Makes it very handy for inserting columns into some sql insert statements or editing of any tabular type data.  This cool Alt+C feature that I just learned thanks to you can be used with it too. You can select the column of text and then hit Alt+C if you want just specific rows to have these numbers added.

Comment: Why didn't I already know to use Alt-C for 30,000+ rows ....

Comment: Jim.. wow. This is such an amazing solution lol