# Is there a way to automatically add the same HTML tags, over and over, to different pieces of text? Maybe with Microsoft Word or Excel?

Tags: html, tags

I would like to list items in an online shop, and I have certain HTML tags that are the same for every item description.

However, I have over 100 items and I would like to format them all in the same way.

I realize this could be done in CSS, but it's not really possible in my situation for complicated reasons.

Is there a way in Excel or maybe Word, that I can have these HTML tags copied and pasted on the start and end of my descriptions automatically?

Your help would be much appreciated, thank you!

An example of my code :

```
<p><strong> Designed in Paris.</strong></p>

<p><span style="line-height: 1.6em;"> Scarf from the NEXT collection.</span></p>

<p> This item is stylish yet elegant, and adds a unique tone to your outfit.</p>

<p><span style="line-height: 1.6em;"> Available in several colours.</span></p>

<div align="center">
<hr align="center" size="2" width="100%" /></div>

<p>Material:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Silk</p>

<p>Length:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ca. 38 cm</p>

<p>Width:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ca. 2,5 cm</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using regular expressions.

**Step one:** Add line numbers to every item description. It is described in following answer:
[Line's number using regex in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636539/lines-number-using-regex-in-notepad)

**Step two:** Prepare regex for every line: [image]

**Step three:** Run regexes for every description (notepad++)

**Edit: added samples.**

Sample regexes for wrapping first line with paragraph tag:

```
Find: (^0001.*)
Replace: \1</p>

Find: (^0001)(.*)
Replace: \1<p>\3
```