# adding line numbers to the end on a line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Can I use notepad++ to add a line number(or any number) and increment then for each line using regex**.I know I can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636539/lines-number-using-regex-in-notepad) at the beginning of the line but how eo I do it at the end of the line?

```
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-
[[33m9625c19e03a747457162d7c0274d75b154a0b926[[m commit-
[[33m8668df12af9eee540cc29f9deb6d31d873bb8f24[[m commit-
[[33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744[[m commit-
[[33m3bcecc602a70fb60324777831d51c81b6f9ccaa7[[m commit-
[[33m0485a39c37e72eabb4003e07a6b8cbae7a0d4e25[[m commit-
[[33m9d3b04a7bcbb82be8b6b7882511f8133745c93b6[[m commit-
[[33m22c259497571390fdd1461f0dd6b77244851984b[[m commit-
[[33m39fb965fc245be55bb86491b5871dd2def08fdf4[[m commit-
[[33m299f6bb77e922d707c9981a48d4d75f57b724719[[m commit-
[[33me7285377d7afc08c7a5fb0ca44154d2de7e1d275[[m commit-
[[33mb3360786ef13044d13b6e58c2239cce5595a1abf[[m commit-
[[33m9af4c134e0d239d1c34fc6bb6087f0473c187fd5[[m commit-
[[33md55ac3370f506a4bbf8a4690b9285e5de9c6a671[[m commit-
[[33me50ef5f58b18d05c36343114804d8be180d26bcb[[m commit-
[[33m962e4a8de7649e06df29f9058a600f8318caf023[[m commit-
[[33m37f5363f62a3f973fe6e0d516e47b4324186d998[[m commit-
[[33m0033e32339e4dc0cce8bd208d43b18a4e9ab43d9[[m commit-
[[33m345239c740a408826f1df0dc5592d5d6b355f019[[m commit-
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-
```

this is what I want:

```
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-1
[[33m9625c19e03a747457162d7c0274d75b154a0b926[[m commit-2
[[33m8668df12af9eee540cc29f9deb6d31d873bb8f24[[m commit-3
...
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-N
```

---

### EDIT1

Some options with a script/command line:

```
$ cat number_at_line_end
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-
...
[33m345239c740a408826f1df0dc5592d5d6b355f019[[m commit-
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-

$ awk -v i=1 '{print $0 i++ }' number_at_line_end
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-1
[[33m9625c19e03a747457162d7c0274d75b154a0b926[[m commit-2
[[33m8668df12af9eee540cc29f9deb6d31d873bb8f24[[m commit-3
...
[[33m345239c740a408826f1df0dc5592d5d6b355f019[[m commit-19
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-20
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-21

$ awk '{print $0 i++ }' number_at_line_end
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-0
[[33m9625c19e03a747457162d7c0274d75b154a0b926[[m commit-1
[[33m8668df12af9eee540cc29f9deb6d31d873bb8f24[[m commit-2
...
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-19
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-20

## counting down
$ a="$(wc -l number_at_line_end | cut -f1 -d' ')" | awk -v i="$a" '{print $0 i-- }' number_at_line_end
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-21
[[33m9625c19e03a747457162d7c0274d75b154a0b926[[m commit-20
...
[[33m345239c740a408826f1df0dc5592d5d6b355f019[[m commit-3
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-2
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the solution provided by the linked QA, then do a little regex to put your line numbers to the end:

- Install TextFX plugin, if not already done
- Mark your whole file content
- TextFX -> TextFX Tools -> Insert Line Numbers
- Open the replace dialog (CTRL + H)
- Check regular expressions
- Search pattern: `0+(\d+) (.*)`
- Replace pattern: $2$1

Comment: tks, that's great. can you just explain `$2$1` tks. is $2 the line number inserted

Comment: ah think, `(\d+)` is $1(the line number in this format `00000003 `) and (.*) is $2(the rest of the line after the line number and the space e.g. `[[33...commit-` ). And then you just replace them by swapping them around with $2$1, so argument 2 is placed first followed by argument 1.

Comment: `$1` is without the leading zeros (they are outside the capturing group), but apart from that you are correct. `$N` in a replacement pattern is a backreference to the nth capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

By pressing on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ move mouse from first line to last line, you select the last column.

Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, in the dialog box, choose initial number `1` and increment `1` then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

If the lines are not the same length, select the column after the longest one. After you have inserted the numbers, just do a replacement: `\s*(\d+)$` --> `$1`

Comment: tks.Can do the alt+C bit and then the numbers from 1 - 21 show at the start of the line(can do this with a leading zero). then can't do the rest,`\s*(\d+)$` does not find anything. (^\d+) (\[\[.*$), this finds 1 to 9, but that is as far as I got.

Comment: @HattrickNZ: You have to select the last column, press Alt and left click the mouse at the end of the first line then move down the mouse until the last line.

Comment: tks, that done the trick, did not know you could, select the last column like that.