# How to select entire line by a number?

Tags: regex

Could you please tel me regular expression that allows me to select certain lines(for example the entire line number 6)?

Comment: in which environment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636539/lines-number-using-regex-in-notepad

Comment: @sweaver2112 something like `^(.*\n){5}(.*[^\n])\n(.*\n)*.*$`  with global and insensitive flags, as long as you know which group you're after (2, in this case).  https://regex101.com/r/H0Secw/1  and now i see you edited your comment =)

Comment: ps2goat perhaps you're right. but yours isn't quite working for me this one seems ok though `(?:.*?\n){5}(.*?\n).*`  https://regex101.com/r/vHl8QG/1

Comment: I am using `Sublime Text 3` editor and none of the above seems to work.

Comment: just tried it ST3 and it works. line 6 is in `$1`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:.*?\n){5}(.*?\n).*
```

note the 'grouping only' parens to eat up everything *up to* line 6, then we just grab that whole line and we're done, line 6 should be in match group #1.  for sublime text this should be `$1`

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vHl8QG/1)